# Primefaces migration: org.primefaces.util.FileUploadUtils.isValidType The type of the uploaded file could not be validated

Tags: primefaces

I'm migrating Primefaces 6.2 to 7.0 and I encountered following problem:
That's my component for file upload

```
                    <p:fileUpload id="fileupload"
                                  label="#{msg['page.application-decisions.selectFile']}"
                                  value="#{decisionBean.uploadedFile}"
                                  style="display: flex; "
                                  styleClass="button like-link font-14 -margin-bottom-20"
                                  mode="advanced"
                                  multiple="false"
                                  auto="true"
                                  dragDropSupport="false"
                                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/"
                                  sizeLimit="10000000"
                                  invalidSizeMessage="#{msg['page.application-decisions.invalidSizeMessage']}"
                                  invalidFileMessage="#{msg['page.application-decisions.invalidFileMessage']}"
                                  fileLimitMessage="#{msg['page.application-decisions.fileLimitMessage']}"
                                  fileUploadListener="#{decisionBean.handleFileUpload}"
                                  disabled="#{decisionBean.application.anyDecisionNotNotified==true}"
                                  update="filemsg fileupload uploadedFileName @this">
                    </p:fileUpload>
```

On Pf 6.2 component uploads file properly, but in PF 7.0 i have error with stacktrace:

```
07-Nov-2023 10:28:39.858 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.primefaces.util.FileUploadUtils.isValidType The type of the uploaded file attachmentExample.pdf could not be validated
    javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: JavaScript ScriptEngine not available via the context ClassLoader or the extension ClassLoader.
        at org.primefaces.util.FileUploadUtils.isValidFileName(FileUploadUtils.java:177)
        at org.primefaces.util.FileUploadUtils.isValidType(FileUploadUtils.java:145)
        at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.NativeFileUploadDecoder.isValidFile(NativeFileUploadDecoder.java:118)
        at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.NativeFileUploadDecoder.decodeAdvanced(NativeFileUploadDecoder.java:111)
        at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.NativeFileUploadDecoder.decode(NativeFileUploadDecoder.java:56)
        at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer.decode(FileUploadRenderer.java:60)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:832)
        at javax.faces.component.UIInput.decode(UIInput.java:773)
```

If I delete allowTypes parameter, there's no error but I need validation for .pdf extension

Comment: I would suggest to read: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6461#issuecomment-717944938

we later removed the usage of JS engine.